# Calling a task from a plug-in that may be not present

Tags: scala, sbt

Depending on a setting I need to call either `package` or `assembly` but obviously the assembly task is from `sbt-assembly` plugin that may not be added. My task looks something like this

```
lazy val useAssembly = settingKey[Boolean]("Use assembly")

lazy val myTask = Def.task {
  val file = if (useAssembly.value) {
    // somehow call assembly here
    } else {
      (`package` in Compile).value
    }

  // Do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`PluginsDebug.autoPluginMap`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/8af7a5acaef783b69d0f4c88d348ac3d90c753ad/main/src/main/scala/sbt/internal/PluginsDebug.scala#L139) may be used to get available auto plugins. Create `project/AssemblyIsAvailable.scala` like so

```
package sbt.internal

/** If sbt-assembly is loaded, then it should be listed as sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin **/
object AssemblyIsAvailable {
  def apply(state: sbt.State): Boolean = {
    PluginsDebug
      .autoPluginMap(state)
      .values
      .toList
      .map(_.label)
      .exists(_.contains("ssembly"))
  }
}
```

then define [dynamic task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29384375/5205022) `assemblyOrDefaultPackage` to be able to use conditional task evaluation within a task:

```
lazy val assemblyOrDefaultPackage = Def.taskDyn {
  if (AssemblyIsAvailable(state.value))
    Def.task { assembly.value }
  else
    Def.task { (Compile / Keys.`package`).value }
}
```

Now `assemblyOrDefaultPackage` can be evaluated within another task like so

```
lazy val myTask = Def.task {
  val file = assemblyOrDefaultPackage.value
  // Do other stuff
}
```

Alternatively, define custom command `assemblyOrDefaultPackage` in `build.sbt` like so

```
commands += Command.command("assemblyOrDefaultPackage") { state =>
  (if (AssemblyIsAvailable(state)) "assembly" else "package") :: state
}
```

Now executing `sbt assemblyOrDefaultPackage` should package with `sbt-assembly` if available, otherwise fallback to default packaging.

Comment: I'm still kinda lost. First, I have a task not command, second, how do I get the value of `assembly` which is needed to perform additional steps in my task?